# What is the commutator of two tangent vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry

I’m trying to visualize what is the meaning of the commutator of 2 derivations, as this is very non intuitive for me.

On a point of a manifold, you can define a tangent vector. This is done by selecting a Curve $\gamma$ on the manifold, and then define the tangent vector as the directional derivative operator along the curve.

As an operator $C^\infty(M) \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, this is of course a derivation.

Then you extend the tangent vectors to tangent vector fields, and these can be viewed as $C^\infty(M) \Rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ operators, which are again derivations, this time on $C^\infty(M)$.

So now you can define the commutator of two tangent vector fields.

Of course, the commutator of two derivations is again a derivation.

I know the proof of this, it’s a simple algebraic manipulation. But, i cannot understand the intuitive meaning of why it’s true.

So what i would like to undestand is, how do you construct the tangent vector field (in terms of a directional derivative operation along a curve at each point) that corresponds to the commutator of 2 tangent vector fields?

I assume that should be possible, right?

It should be again a directional derivative operation along Some curve, and that should help me understand what is happening..

Comment: Google Lie derivative of vector fields. You should see lots of pictures (and if you don’t, also search for “Lie derivative using flows” or something along those lines). Note that the picture isn’t going to be super obvious, because you need an entire vector field for this, not just two vectors at a single point (i.e you can’t just take two curves and create a new curve). One vector field generates a flow (a 1-parameter family group of diffeomorphisms) which is then used to pullback another vector field, and you’re differentiating that result.